# Widevine License Renewal from Azure

Tags: azure, exoplayer, azure-media-services, exoplayer2.x

I have a question concerning widevine license renewal with azure media services ,

Im trying to renew a license from the azure license service using the dynamic license URL provided in the manifest , but when i do the renewal on exoplayer using the offlineHelper class ( offlineLicenseHelper.renewLicense ) , the license service always returns THE SAME CONTENT KEY knowing that i have declared can_renew : true in my widevine content key policy template.

is there something wrong with what i'm doing ?

Any answer can help.

Thank you.

Comment: The usage of renewLicense  is  `offlineLicenseHelper.renewLicense(offlineLicenseKeySetId);`. You need provide more details when error occus.

Answer (score 0):

yes indeed that is the function that I'm using right now, here's how I'm using it :

```
keySetId =mediaItem.playbackProperties.drmConfiguration.getKeySetId();
android.util.Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: Old key : "+ Arrays.toString(keySetId));
newkeySetId = offlineLicenseHelper.renewLicense(keySetId);   
android.util.Log.d(TAG,"doInBackground:newkey:"+Arrays.toString(newkeySetId));
```

and an example result of my testing in the log is this :

```
doInBackground: Old key : [107, 115, 100, 69, 69, 55, 51,  57, 54, 65, 54]
doInBackground: New key : [107, 115, 100, 69, 69, 55, 51,  57, 54, 65, 54]
```

Both KeysetId and newKeySetId produce the same value and the server's license URL that i'm using is this :

https://swannmediaservice.keydelivery.westeurope.media.azure.net/Widevine/?kid=a2711bd1-f1c6-42f0-b6bc-06ec12405d3c

the above is just an example of a dymanic url that azure media services provides with the manifest.

but i think it's because the value kid=a2711bd1-f1c6-42f0-b6bc-06ec12405d3c always returns the same keyid even tho i requested a new keyid.

I'm not sure if azure doesn't support key renewals on dynamic URLs or what?!

Answer (score 0):

For Widevine requests, we take the template as a string. We should be sending whatever information you provide in the template all the way through to the Google Widevine server.

I have not tested this flow myself, but when we get a Widevine request on the Key Delivery service, we just fill in details such as keyID, and sign it with our key. We don’t really do anything else other than that and send the request on to the license server hosted by Google for Widevine. We do not alter any part or the template in the actual license request.

The policyoverride object comes from the you as part of the WidevineConfiguration when creating ContentKeyPolicy.  We do not set or alter the **renewal_server_url** that is set in there.

Are you sure that you have a valid template? If you can file an official support ticket with all the details on the account, and the template being used we can follow up.